# How to give custom divider in container?

Tags: flutter

I need to give this divider but I don't know how to coding it .

[image]

I tried but I don't know how to give thin to thick .

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use container with gradient instead of Divider.

```
Container(
 height: 2,
 width: 100,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: <Color>[
              Color.green.withOpacity(0.1),
              Color.green,
              Color.green.withOpacity(0.1),
            ], 
          ),
        ),
    ),
```

This is only for divider with that effect.
for content above and below you can use Column widget

```
Column (
 children: [
  widget1,
  divider,
  widget2,
 ]
)
```

change height, width, color and opacity as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter widget

```
Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Text('Title'),
          Divider(thickness: 5,color: Colors.black,),
          Text('Description'),
        ],),
```

Comment: I need to give thin start of the divider then it will be thick center of the divider then again it will be thin.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you should use to solve your problem

```
Divider(thickness: 2,color:Colors.grey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use The Container With Gradient instead of Divider.
Like This:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  height: 4,
 child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          colors: [
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.red,
          ],
        )
      ),
  ),
),
```